# Difference between negation and inequality in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, logic

What is the difference between `if !variable == 10 {...}` and `if variable != 10 {...}` in Ruby programming language? Of course this can be applied to all other languages. In first case are we just negating condition, and in second testing if variable is actually unequal to 10?

Comment: You are intending to use `==` as opposed to `=` there.

Comment: @Makoto, exactly, thanks, it is a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if variable != 10` is equivalent to `unless variable == 10`
while `!variable` is negating the variable, so first it's evaluated as an expression, then negated.

Example

```
variable = 5
variable != 10 # => true
!variable # => false (5 is evaluated to true, then negated)
!variable = 10 # => warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
```

Comment: Or `!(variable == 10)` or lower precedence `not(variable == 10)`

Answer (score 2):

To a large degree all programming languages, including Ruby, follow [boolean algebra rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) that state there's a number of ways to express the same condition.

```
x != y
!(x == y)
!!(x != y)
```

This also plays out in other domains, such as:

```
!x && !y
!(x || y)
```

As others have pointed out, be very careful when using the `==` *comparator* instead of the `=` `assignment` operator.